# ENOENT error in React app when running "npm start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am developing a React application and I am encountering an error when I try to run "npm start". The error message is as follows:

```
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Mantu Kumbhakar\AppData\Local\Temp;C:'
    at Object.realpathSync (node:fs:2580:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mantu Kumbhakar\Desktop\React-Projects\hello-react\node_modules\temp-dir\index.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mantu Kumbhakar\Desktop\React-Projects\hello-react\node_modules\tempy\index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Mantu Kumbhakar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp;C:'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\cache\_logs\2023-04-22T05_01_29_565Z-debug.log
```

It seems that there is a missing directory in the temporary folder that the application is trying to access. I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling all dependencies, clearing the npm cache, checking the path to the temporary folder in my code, and ensuring that the required directory exists and has the necessary permissions. However, the error still persists.

here is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "heyreact",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I am using Node.js v18.16.0 and npm v6.14.4 on a Windows 10 machine. I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.